# convert/decode a mail "quoted-printable" string from a variable with javax.mail.internet.MimeUtility or an other way?

Tags: jakarta-mail, decode, quoted-printable

I have a text content of an .eml file that I put in a variable and I would parse its content, including converting different formats.
If in the header an "quoted-printable" string have surrounded tags =? Utf-8? Q? ....? =
the mimeUtlility.decodeText () function works well, but if I have a coded text "quoted-printable" in the body of the email without these tags, mimeUtlility.decodeText () of javax.mail.internet.MimeUtility does not.
How can I decode these texts of different formats and charsets?
  an example of a portion of text: "Cell Manager
         S = = E9 E9curit / Pr = E9vention / Suret = E9 "
and sometimes there are "=CRLF" at end of lines

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [MimeUtility.decode](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeUtility.html#decode-java.io.InputStream-java.lang.String-) method.

The bigger question might be why you're doing all this work yourself.  If you have the data in a .eml file, JavaMail should be able to read it, parse it, and decode it for you.

Comment: Hello
in fact I avoid to have a .eml file, I directly put the text of the email .eml format in a text variable.
I tried mimeUtility.decode (text variable, "quoted-printable"), but it does not work because the function decode(java.io.InputStream is, java.lang.String encoding) requires an InputStream, and I don't  know how to put the variable text in an InputStream

Comment: If you're creating a MIME-format message "by hand" (instead of using JavaMail to do that), and you're storing it in a String containing only ASCII characters, you can use the deprecated [StringBufferInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/StringBufferInputStream.html).  You can use that with MimeUtility.decode, or even simpler use it with the MimeMessage constructor that takes an InputStream.  But again, what problem are you solving by creating the raw MIME message text yourself?

Comment: I put the string into an inputstream with 
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(string.getBytes());
but the result of decode is "com.sun.mail.util.QPDecoderStream@1a3a420" and i don't know what it means

Comment: yes I Storing mail into a variable with javax.mail to save time because that is apparently (?) faster than creating a .eml file. then parse it. But I'll try other ways to do next.

Comment: I wasn't questioning the need to avoid creating a file, I was questioning the approach of creating a raw MIME format message in a String vs. using JavaMail to create the MIME format message.  Also, what are you doing with the message after you create it?

Comment: i don't create a message, i import a message from my mailbox into a variable and i parse it

Comment: Why aren't you using JavaMail to do that?

Comment: I managed to get the desired result by adding BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (QPdecode, "UTF-8"));
Thanks a lot

Comment: BufferedReader isn't decoding quoted-printable.  What's "QPdecode" in your example?

Comment: I import it with javamail

Comment: InputStream is = new StringBufferInputStream(string)

InputStream QPdecode =  javax.mail.internet.MimeUtility.decode(is, code)

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(QPdecode,charset));
and code = "quoted-printable" and charset = "utf-8"

Comment: I think we need to step back and look at the bigger picture here.  If you're using JavaMail to read the message from your mailbox, you should (generally) **never** need to use the MimeUtility class or need to decode quoted-printable content yourself.  If you're using JavaMail correctly, JavaMail will do all that decoding for you, transparently.  What exactly are you doing that makes you want to decode the content yourself?

Comment: I repeat, I import mime entire message then parse the suite to save time instead of importing the subject, then the date, then the message and attachments with javamail forcing each time to parse the same message, so open the email box at each time and prevents the to be read

Comment: I extracted separately the subject, the message and others in fields of a filemaker base

Comment: JavaMail doesn't parse the message each time.  If you're reading the message from an IMAP server, the server parses the message, JavaMail only has to parse the IMAP protocol commands.  Using the Folder.fetch method, the values of various fields can be prefetched so that each doesn't require a separate command to the server.  Maybe you could share more details of the code you're using and the performance testing you've done that shows your approach is an improvement?  Maybe I don't understand what you're doing, but it sounds like you're making the problem harder for no reason.

Comment: Hello
sorry for my poor English because I'm French :)
 the goal is to feed a filemaker database with different informations from mails. So I have a filemaker script that will import each message and distribute information in different fields. First the headers, subject, date, from, to, cc, and the message itself, preferably html and finally attachments.

Comment: I chose as a method to import one by one unread messages with FlagTerm ft = new FlagTerm (new Flags (Flags.Flag.SEEN), false);
  folder.search messages = (ft);
After that the messages are tagged as read.
So I import a message and then successively extracted each  information for split it properly. So I have a javascript script for each action. The first opens the IMAP inbox and will look for a message, a second will extract the subject of the message stored in text filemaker, a third date and etc
I'm open to other ways of doing but I admit to not see how to do it otherwise

Comment: I don't understand how you're using JavaScript vs. what you're doing with Java and JavaMail.  Is the JavaScript executing in the browser?  Is the Java executing on the server?  How does the data get from the server to the browser?  Is the FileMaker database on the server?  Why do you need to copy the data from the IMAP server to the FileMaker database server?

Comment: I did not need a browser. In filemaker I have an extension (addon) that allows me to execute JavaScript or groovy code. My filemaker database  is not server because it is for me alone for now accessed to my various spots

Comment: in filemaker there is also a web viewer, a kind of internal browser from Internet Explorer that allows you to access the net and also to execute javascript

Comment: Is your Java code running in your FileMaker addon, running in FileMaker locally on your desktop/laptop?  Does it copy the content of mail messages from the remote mail server into database tables in FileMaker?  Still, there's no reason you should need to decode the content of the mail messages yourself.  Just use the JavaMail APIs to extract the various fields as Java Unicode Strings and store the results in the database.

Comment: hello
"Is your Java code running in your FileMaker addon, running in FileMaker locally on your desktop/laptop?" yes it is

Comment: "Does it copy the content of mail messages from the remote mail server into database tables in FileMaker?" it is my goal

Comment: and if I convert an email in .eml file, can I use the getSubject () getFrom () etc of javax.mail with this file ?

Comment: yes I can do it with
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(FilePath);
MimeMessage mime = new MimeMessage(null, is);
Then I'm looking for how getting the body message and the attachments

Comment: If you copy the entire raw MIME content of a message into the database, and then later fetch it from the database, you can use the MimeMessage constructor above to create a new MimeMessage that will then allow you to access the entire content of the message using the MimeMessage and related APIs.  There's lots of JavaMail examples showing how to access the content (subject, date, body, attachments, etc.) using those APIS.  Alternatively, you can use those APIs before you store the message in the database, and instead store just the results from those API calls.  Either way will work.

Comment: Start at the [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#examples).